# iOS: Php Soap Server to retrieve data gives (apos); error

Tags: php, ios, xml, web-services, soap

I am creating a php web service as below, when calling that web service I am getting below error in response string. I don't understand where exactly issue is,

```
-(void)requestNotifyData{

    //build up the request that is to be sent to the server
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://golf.demo.com/webservices/service.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"getUpdates" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];

    //create data that will be sent in the post
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setValue:@"" forKey:@"user_location"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"free" forKey:@"application_type"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"2014-11-25" forKey:@"last_updated_date"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"ios" forKey:@"platform"];

    //serialize the dictionary data as json
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&jsonError];

    [request setHTTPBody:data]; //set the data as the post body
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

I am getting an error string in response as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">method &apos;&apos;(&apos;&apos;) not defined in service(&apos;&apos; &apos;&apos;)</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What would be the issue ? I am confused.

Comment: Looks like the server doesn't know what "service" you're running.  See if the documentation indicates how to identify the service.  Good luck, looks really (overly?) complicated.  Must be a very complex service to involve all this.